# How to declare variables in select statement

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, t-sql, select

Please look at this query.

```
select name form table
```

Let suppose this returns 100 name records.

I want to store each record in variable and then use this variable in another select

statement.Perhaps I have to do it with inner select but I do not know how.

How this is possible ?

I am working on three complex queries with complex joins I use the code of product and pass them to queries .If first query return the result fine else I move to second query else to third on.I have done this in c# very easily using loops but it is taking very much time(About 5 minutes for 7000 records)
Now I shall store the code in variable and pass it to first query in SQL if count of it result is greater than 0 fine else I move to 2nd else to third one. And so I shall iterate to all productCode Records.   `select * from productsale where productname like' %';

Comment: Post the queries, im sure it can be done without cursors

Comment: 2 downvotes? I've seen much worse questions that this! Please explain so we can all learn 'the right way'! Hmphh!! ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure the last line in your posting. select * from pSales where Pname like ' %' .. Is that a deliberate space in there? So you're looking for records where Pname begins with a space char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the a reason you're not using JOIN's? That is usually the best way to use a value in one table to extract values from other tables.

Something like

```
   select name , dept from name_table nt, dept_table dt
   where nt.name = dt.name
```

Otherwise you're looking to use cursors. There are a lot of good tutorials on the web, and you may want to find a tutorial specific the DB version you are using.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Zain : you need to tag your question as C# to get the best advice for that environment.

Comment: @Zain Cursor is almost never a good option, not unless you know it's no other way. Let the database do what it does best, set-based queries.

Comment: @ Lasse V. Karlsen I try this with  cursor approach it is taking about 19 secs but when i used set base approach it is taking 21 sec.